# Ruby on Rails passing controller variables to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am having difficulties understanding why the parameter is not passing to the view.

**controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper

  before_filter :set_user, :set_categories
  def show
    @test = get_test()
  end
end
```

**helper**

```
module UsersHelper
   def get_test()
     puts "hello world"
   end
end
```

**view**

```
test:  <%= @test %>
```

What is being displayed `test:`

Can someone please give me some assistance of why `hello world` is not being displayed? Thanks!

--Edit--
It seems like I am not able to even pass any variable messages to the view
I added... 
**controller**

```
@message = "How are you"
```

**view**

```
<p><%= @message %></p>
```

And `How are you` is not displaying.

Comment: have you defined `@message` inside relevant action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `get_test` function, you are printing a string instead of returning the string. To return a string:

```
module UsersHelper
   def get_test()
     "hello world"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that did solve the problem! would you have happen to know how to solve my edit?

Comment: How would you return a variable, would it just be `@hello = "hello world"`? Or would it just hello = "hello world", and it would return the local variable?

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand you. You mean to assign a string to a variable?  To return a string from the function you do `return "hello world"`. To let a view access the variable you often have to assign it to a instance variable, which is `@hello = "hello world"`. `hello` without @ would be local variable.